# AngularJS Error: TypeError: angular.extend is not a function ... angular-sanitize.js Line 186

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm getting this error occasionally, does not seem to be any pattern to when it occurs. It started happening when I started using the ngSanitize for adding ng-html-bind attributes to some elements. Again it doesn't seem to happen all the time. I don't understand the internals of Angular to really get why this coming up. Any insight would be appreciated. Thanks.

This is from firebug:

```
TypeError: angular.extend is not a function
http://localhost:8500/ev2/apps/folio/app/lib/angular/angular-sanitize.js
Line 186
```

This is from chrome developer tools:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'extend' 
(anonymous function) angular-sanitize.js:184
(anonymous function) angular-sanitize.js:622
```

Secondary error (which I assume is caused because of the first):

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module folio due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module ngSanitize due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.6/$injector/nomod?p0=ngSanitize
```

Comment: Same problem here with 1.2.15

Answer (score 0):

I was encountering the same problem, also right after implementing `ng-bind-html` attributes. It seems like angular-sanitize.js has a dependency on angular.js. I'm loading dependencies with $script, and haven't had the error since loading angular.js first, i.e.:

```
...
<script src="lib/angular-1.2.18/angular.js"></script>
<script>
    $script([
        //'lib/angular-1.2.18/angular.js',
        'lib/angular-1.2.18/angular-routes.js',
        'lib/angular-1.2.18/angular-sanitize.js', ...
```